# How much xp does each mob give me?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How much xp orbs do, zombies, spiders, cave spiders, skeletons, blazes, and players drop?

Comment: I am pretty sure that players drop different amount of xp depending on how much they have but if you can add the formula into your answers that would help a lot. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

According to [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience), we know that most mobs give an average of 1 to 3 experience when slain, and all breeding will net between 1 and 7 experience if successful. Meanwhile, killing baby mobs will net no reward. It also contains a very thorough table on the topic:

| Source | Experience |
| --- | --- |
| ***Animals*** |  |
| Bee, Cat, Chicken, Fish (including Cod, Salmon, Pufferfish and all Tropical Fish), Cow, Fox, Horse (including Donkey, Mule, Skeleton Horse, and Zombie Horse), Llama (including Trader Llama), Mooshroom, Ocelot, Panda, Parrot, Pig, Polar Bear, Rabbit, Sheep, Squid, Dolphin, Turtle, Wolf, Strider‌[BE only] | 1–3 |
| Strider‌[JE only] | 1–2 |
| Bat, all baby animals except hoglins‌[JE only] | 0 |
| ***Golems*** |  |
| Iron Golem, Snow Golem | 0 |
| ***Monsters*** |  |
| Cave Spider, Creeper, Drowned, Enderman, Ghast, Hoglin, Husk, Illusioner, Phantom, Piglin, Pillager, Shulker, Silverfish, Skeleton, Spider, Stray, Vex, Vindicator, Witch, Wither Skeleton, Zombie, Zombie Villager, Zoglin, Zombified Piglin | 5 + 1–3 (per equipment) |
| Endermite | 3 |
| Large Slime and Magma Cube | 4 |
| Medium Slime and Magma Cube | 2 |
| Small Slime and Magma Cube | 1 |
| Baby Husk, Baby Drowned, Baby Zombie, Baby Zombified Piglin, Baby Zombie Villager | 12 + 1–3 (per equipment) |
| Spider Jockey | 5 (skeleton) + 1–3 (per equipment) + 5 (spider) |
| Chicken Jockey | 12 (zombie) + 1–3 (per equipment) + 10 (chicken) |
| Blaze, Evoker, Elder Guardian, Guardian | 10 |
| Ravager, Piglin Brute | 20 |
| ***Players and NPCs*** |  |
| Player | 7 per level, up to 100 |
| Agent, NPC, Villager, Wandering trader | 0 |
| ***Bosses*** |  |
| Ender Dragon | 12,000 (500 if respawned with end crystals) |
| Wither | 50 |

The table on the wiki also includes information related to experience dropped by mining blocks, smelting, completing challenges, etc. See the aforementioned wiki article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Every hostile mob drops 5 exp. orbs when they are killed. The value of these orbs can is random though. The exception to this is the blaze, which drops 10 exp. A Player gives 7 per level, up to 100.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this answer seems wrong. Killed mobs drop a random amount of xp orbs, but the total xp is fixed by mob type: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Experience#Experience_amounts_by_source

Comment: @AJPerez this answer is *partially* correct.